# Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, ssis-2016

I built an SSIS project on "test" server, and deployed the project across to "live" server. The project has property ProtectionLevel set to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. Everything deployed successfully.

After fixing an issue within the project, without realising it, I attempted to deploy the project from "live" to "live". When I entered in the password for the project the following error came up:

**Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)**

At the time this completely perplexed me, as I have numerous projects and had never seen this before. Google provided very little help, other than C# references to a certain encryption algorithm. Once I realised that I was trying to deploy on "live" server, I went back to "test" and deployed successfully.

I'll be completely honest, all my other projects had been deployed "live" to "live". This is the first project I had created on "test" and deployed across (perhaps a poor attempt to ease my conscience).

My question is: Why does this error occur? but also, does this mean that I can now only deploy this project to the "live" server from "test". Is it not possible for me to now deploy "live" to "live"?

Thanks in advance for any help/insight in to this.